# How do I convert an (id) parameter to a property list object?

Tags: ios

My app is being launched via a URL and I've added the following method which will be invoked upon launch:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

annotation is described as being a property-list object supplied by the source application. I would like to examine the contents to see what information/data the source application is supplying. How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to convert the `annotation` variable from an `id` to something else. Simply call whatever methods that the object supports directly.

[Property lists](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html) can be an array, dictionary, string, number, boolean, date, and data.

To find out the type of the property list: `[annotation className]`, `[annotation class]`, or `[annotation classCode]`.

All property lists will conform to the `description` and `valueForKey` methods.

```
// Retrieve the contents of a property list as a string.
NSString *contents = [annotation description]
NSLog(@"%@", contents);
```